# How to add python path in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, python, python-2.7

I'm trying to run a scrapy project on a ubuntu server. For which I need to add the project path to python path.

I created a `.bash_profile` file in the `/home` directory with the following contents:

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/john/Desktop/myscraper/
EXPORT $PYTHONPATH
```

But I'm getting error running my python file stating it didn't find the module.

```
ImportError: No module named myscraper.items
```

I tried using the following paths, but nothing works.

- `/home/john/Desktop/myscraper/`
- `/home/john/Desktop/myscraper`
- `home/john/Desktop/myscraper/`
- `home/john/Desktop/myscraper`

Comment: Did you really create it in the `/home` directory - or in your `$HOME` directory? Did you really write `EXPORT` - or `export`?

Comment: I wrote `EXPORT` all in caps, and created the file in the `/home` directory. I don't know what you mean by the `$HOME` directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Config files belong in your personal home directory (`/home/$USER`, `$HOME` or simply `~`), not in the `/home` directory. In your case that will be `/home/john`.

Please also make sure to use the correct casing, it's `export` in all lowercase.

Since `export` is not accessing but referencing the variable, you do not use the `$` sign: `export PYTHONPATH`

Are you sure you want to have this in your `.bash_profile` and not your `.bashrc`? You can read up on the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment).

In any case you will have to run `source ~./bash_profile` (or `source ~./bashrc` if you go with that) for your changes to take effect.

Comment: Just saw the comments by @steeldriver on the question. Sorry for posting duplicate content, credit of first posting this goes to him :)

Comment: It's all good - you might want to point out that the OP will need to log out and back in (or at least start a new login shell or source the `~/.bash_profile`) for the change to take effect

Comment: It says `bash: export: /home/john/Desktop/myscraper:/home/john/Desktop/myscraper not a valid identifier'

Comment: Loose the `$` after the export command and you should be fine: `export PYTHONPATH`
You might want to request for that to be changed in the documentation that you're copying these commands from.

Comment: I'm still getting `ImportError: No module named myscraper.items` error

Comment: Run `echo $PYTHONPATH` to confirm the path has been added correctly. The output should contain `/home/john/Desktop/myscraper`. Debugging the software you're installing goes beyond the scope of this thread.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [NeoTheThird's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1002216/301745):

Ubuntu does not use `~/.bash_profile` by default. You should use `~/.profile` instead.

The path you should use is `/home/john/Desktop/myscraper`, though `/home/john/Desktop/myscraper/` would also work. Paths that don't start with slashes are relative, not absolute, so will not work unless the working directory is `/`. More details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths) on Wikipedia.

You can put the definition and export statements together, and if PYTHONPATH is not already defined, you can leave off the `$PYTHONPATH:` at the start.

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/john/Desktop/myscraper
```

Comment: +1 The hint on the relative path is good, forgot that in my answer.